# Define a instance belong to a certain class

Tags: owl, protege

I want to define an OWL ontology, whose main goal is to explicitly describe the spatial elevation of things. Here is an example, I divide things into three classes, namely above_ground, surface and underground. The concepts of some things may belong to these classes simultaneously. Such as the concept Parking lot should belong to these three classes. However, when instantiating Parking lot, say Pk_xxx, it comes a problem, I can't distinguish which class the instance Pk_xxx belong to.

Comment: not sure what you're asking. Why can't you add `Pk_xxx` to the class it belongs to? I don't get it

Comment: What I want to do is to assign the instance of Parking lot to one of these three classes. And I've solved the problem using covering axioms which is referred to  in ProtegeOWLTutorial.